# Using javascript in Symfony2/Twig with external references

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, external

In reference to the following post:

[Using javascript in Symfony2/Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297594/using-javascript-in-symfony2-twig/11298090#11298090)

Is there a possibility to include scripts locating on other servers, just as google-api.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it without the asset-manager,
just including the script statically.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the script is located on an external server doesn't change much. You can still have Assetic handle it like in the example below.

```
{% block javascripts %}

  {% javascripts 
    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js'
    '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/demo.js'
  %}

    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>

  {% endjavascripts %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In my Project Assetic converts the external URL to an internal:
`'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js'`

results in

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/2bec354_jquery-ui.min_1.js"></script>`

Comment: Assetic not only convert, Assetic download and save external script to local path.